# Using reverse geocode API to return JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, vb.net, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to use the reverse geocode API from geocodefarm.com to get an address using latitude and longitude. When I run this, i get the alert "error", but the geocodefarm status thing says I've used one of my queries... So I know it's going to the url, I'm just not sure exactly how I'm supposed to be getting the JSON and parsing it. it's failing on the getLocation(). any help would be great!

```
<td><button onclick="getLocation();return false;" runat="server"></button></td>
```

Script

```
    function getLocation() {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/reverse/json/*apiKey*/45.2040305/-93.3995728/',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                WriteResponse(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }

function WriteResponse(location) {
        if (location != null) {
            $("#txtAddZipCode").html = location.address
        }
    }
```

this is how the site says it should be returned in JSON form

```
{

    },
    "STATUS": {
        "access": "KEY_VALID, ACCESS_GRANTED",
        "status": "SUCCESS"
    },
           "PROVIDER": {
        "provider": "LOCAL_FARM",
        "import": "ALREADY_STORED"
    },
    "ADDRESS": {
        "address": "522-534 West Main Street, Anoka, MN 55303, USA",
        "accuracy": "GOOD ACCURACY"
    },
    "COORDINATES": {
        "latitude": "45.2040305",
        "longitude": "-93.3995728"
    },
    "STATISTICS": {
        "load_time": "0.52",
        "https_ssl": "DISABLED, INSECURE"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues, firstly you can't do a synchronous ajax call cross-domain, it's not possible so there's no reason to add `async : false`, it's ignored.

Secondly, this is the wrong syntax

```
$("#txtAddZipCode").html = location.address
```

it should be

```
$("#txtAddZipCode").html(location.address);
```

And finally, it seems the URL you're using doesn't support CORS, I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error when running it, but I don't have an API key, so that could be what's causing it.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the first two things, I'm pretty new at this! and yeah, it definitely supports CORS, it must be the key thing. here's a default key  http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/reverse/json/8020663c02e9792285f28c3d576fce3840c82e8a/45.2040305/-93.3995728/

Comment: If I plug that URL in my browser, I get the JSON, but it still lacks the correct headers, so when using ajax I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, meaning it's a same origin policy issue, and the server just doesn't support it.

Comment: ah thank you! I'm super new at this if you can't tell